# How to change size of annotation on move the map?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'am developing an iOS app using swift. The app contains a MKMapView with custom annotation views. I want to change the size of an annotation based on the distance to the center of the view. I know that I can use something like `view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: transformFaktor, y: transformFaktor)` but I don't know where to place it and how to get the view from an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIGraphics` to change the size of an annotation.

e.g.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let image = UIImage(named: "Image name here")
    let resizedSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizedSize)
    image?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: resizedSize))
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin")
    annotationView.image = resizedImage
    return annotationView
}
```